# How do I test this static member in a class with private constructor?

Tags: java, junit

So my class is:

```java
public final class MyClass {

    private static MyObject myObject;

    public static void setMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        MyClass.myObject = myObject;
    }

    private MyClass(MyObject myObject){
        setMyObject(myObject);
    }

    public static Optional<Object2> getObject2(params) {
        Optional<Object2> object2 =  myObject.execute(params);
        return object2;
    }
```

I'm trying to test with Junit

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private MyObject myObject;

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Mockito.doReturn(Optional.empty()).when(myObject).executeQueryWithArgument(any);
        myclass = new Myclass(myObject);

    }
}
```

```java
        myclass = new Myclass(myObject);
```

This line fails and says make MyClass constructor package private. Is there any way to do this without doing that?

Comment: You can do it using reflection. But you should probably design you class as the JUnit/Mockito suggests. If you do have a real reson for the constructor to be private, don't test it. Test just the public interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add mocked `myObject` to the `MyClass` using the set method and write the test, like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private MyObject myObject;

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MyClass.setMyObject(myObject);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        // Arrange
        Mockito.doReturn(Optional.empty()).when(myObject).executeQueryWithArgument(any);

       // Act
        Optional<Object2> actual = myClass.getObject2(.....);

       // Assert
       .....
    }
}
```